# CEP/CEL executing out of order

Tags: cumulocity

We have a CEL/CEP executing every time a new measurement is created. We have noticed that some CELs triggered by older measurements execute before CELs triggered by newer measurements. (ie in the wrong order). In addition, sometimes CELs are executing hours after the measurements that triggered them were received. Sometimes, CELs are not being triggered at all and do not execute.

We use CELs to raise alarms, convert data points to the expected units of measurement and set/clear UI transient states and the above issues are causing multiple problems in our Application sometimes rendering it unusable.

The problems stated above have appeared or become evident after the outage experienced by C8y in September. It seems that CELs throttling is more strict and this is creating long queues of CELs pending execution.

Have you experienced these problems? Any suggestions/strategy on how to best deal with them would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Alvaro Valderrama

Comment: Maybe you can provide some code where you are actually encounter this problem. From the use cases you describe everything seems to be stateless. In general the order of processing the events is not guaranteed to be the same as you send them in. If this problem is just about having poor performance on the system you should contact the support instead of asking for development advice.